# Simple Android Studio project gives NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a simple app that has 1 Activity and a few application classes to do work inside it. I'm using the latest Android Studio, a freshly generated barebones project, api level 23 (for android 6.0.1, my phone).

I can deploy, open and use my app mostly fine, except that I keep getting an error at runtime in the VM when I start calling project classes external to the Activity I'm working in: stacktrace at the bottom.

What's supposed to happen is

1. Activity logs that it will call external class
2. performs call, external class does some very minor work
3. external class logs that it will begin doing serious work

The first log statement is reached, and then suddenly execution seems to just stop and the external class' log line never arrives, then a minute later I get the error. I get the feeling my external classes aren't being included in compilation or something like that.

I've been a java dev for a while but I have next to no experience with android dev and gradle.

Here's my project: https://gitlab.com/Marnes/leaumar.net-android

The relevant classes are in https://gitlab.com/Marnes/leaumar.net-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/leaumar/net/filedump

The relevant code section is the bottom of HomeActivity, where an upload test is performed and PresetUpload is called. The message that data is about to be posted never appears.

> 03-11 13:39:49.998 5295-5295/leaumar.net.filedump I/leaumar.net.filedump.HomeActivity: user wants to test upload
>   **03-11 13:39:49.999 5295-5295/leaumar.net.filedump I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class**
>   **03-11 13:39:49.999 5295-5295/leaumar.net.filedump I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class**
>   **03-11 13:41:05.139 5295-5381/leaumar.net.filedump I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class**
>   03-11 13:41:05.140 5295-5381/leaumar.net.filedump E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>   Process: leaumar.net.filedump, PID: 5295
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>   ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: leaumar.net.filedump.http.PresetUpload$1
>   ...
>   03-11 13:41:05.141 5295-5295/leaumar.net.filedump I/Choreographer: Skipped 4508 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: Have you tried using a search engine to understand the nature of this kind of exception?

Comment: I know what it means, I'm not new to java. I am new to android dev and gradle and such (I always used maven and desktop java). I don't know why I'm getting an error that implies my classes aren't being created, who isn't creating them or why they're disappearing, why my project packages aren't being compiled while the main activity is, etc. And googling my overall problems hasn't really given me anything I can work with, like "if you add project classes to the package where activities are put by default, add a reference to those packages in gradle.build" or something

Comment: Fair enough then. But you might want to edit the question then, we don't need hundreds of lines of that stack trace. Me, personally I would start with a step by step tutorial to learn how to get the various settings right. And just for the record, I didn't downvote here.

Comment: I've looked in a bunch of places but nobody says anything about it (and many examples don't even make classes outside their Activity). Nowhere does anyone say "oh yeah if you want to make some classes outside your Activity, you have to do this and that". Nobody remarks on it and I don't see why you can't just put other classes next to your Activity in your main package  in the java dir (which is practically the same structure as maven), so I somehow doubt my problem is a rookie mistake.

Comment: The point is that your other classes are not in the class path when that JVM runs your activity. I guess that they are not part of your "deployed" package. But I am an too infrequent user of this stack to give more helpful input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to

1. add a new module
2. choose "android library" as type
3. put your classes in there
4. go to project structure and set this new module as dependency of your main module

Problem is now I'm getting a build error despite everything looking fine in the IDE...

> :impl:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
>   An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_91). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for java.lang.invoke.MethodType not found
>   :impl:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

Comment: well, to solve that, I lowered the language level on the library module to 1.7 and removed any java 8 features... it works now